# ADFS : Acquiring a Token programmatically

Tags: azure, adfs, azure-ad-msal

So we have built a set of Azure Functions that are secured by ADFS (MSAL)

We have configured an App in ADFS and got it all working well with our Android client.

We now want to do some API testing so we want to programmatically generate Auth tokens to test the API's

I can't get the following code to work at all, maybe I have the tenant ID wrong, in the App config, its a GUID (42b03d0b-d7f2-403e-b764-0dbdcf0505f6), but examples say it's our domain

```
string userName = "-";
string password = "-";
string clientId = "ee13c922-bf4b-4f0a-ba39-ea74e1203c6e";
var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/acostaonline.onmicrosoft.com");
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientId, credentials);
```

**UPDATE**

So changed the code to be MSAL and still trying to login via username and password.  Now it just times out

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/42b03d0b-d7f2-403e-b764-0dbdcf0505f6/";
string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
PublicClientApplication app = new PublicClientApplication("ee13c922-bf4b-4f0a-ba39-ea74e1203c6e", authority);
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult result = null;
      if (accounts.Any())
      {
         result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault());
      }
      else
      {
          try
          {
             var securePassword = new SecureString();
             foreach (char c in "PASSWORD")        // you should fetch the password keystroke
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // by keystroke

             result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordAsync(scopes, "AUSER@acosta.com",
                                                                           securePassword);
          }
     }
```

**Error**

> SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   172.26.200.77:443

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code you provided is using ADAL instead of MSAL.

The main difference is that with `ADAL` you would use an `AuthenticationContext` to acquire tokens, whereas in `MSAL` you use `ConfidentialClientApplication` or `PublicClientApplication`, depending on if the application is running in a back-end or on the user's device.

Here is the article about [Differences between ADAL.NET and MSAL.NET applications](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal).

When you use MSAL.Net to get a token for the Microsoft Graph API, you could use the following code:

```
public static PublicClientApplication PublicClientApp = new 
PublicClientApplication(ClientId);
var app = App.PublicClientApp;
ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault());
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop#use-msal-to-get-a-token-for-the-microsoft-graph-api), in left menu also includes [Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android#use-msal-to-get-a-token) and [iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-ios#use-the-microsoft-authentication-library-msal-to-get-a-token-for-the-microsoft-graph-api).

Comment: So can you not do this programmatically using a username and password for things like API testing.

Comment: With ADAL ? Or with MSAL?

Comment: Could you show more details about your timeout? [Token renewal operation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/209) or just when acquire token?

Comment: @Burf2000 Is there a firewall in your LAN or Intranet? And accessing internet via proxy server?